# What is a shopping question part 5 (How can I solve problem Y? Answer: You should buy X)

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Sometimes users will ask **How can I solve problem Y and then the other answers will recommend product Y**, are these off or on-topic?

For example,

1. [What's the best or easiest way to attach a loop tag onto canvas?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/17346/whats-the-best-or-easiest-way-to-attach-a-loop-tag-onto-canvas)
2. [How to keep paper from being damaged by water in the outdoors?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/19195/how-to-keep-paper-from-being-damaged-by-water-in-the-outdoors)
3. [How can I take keys with me while swimming?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/16770/how-can-i-take-keys-with-me-while-swimming/16787#16787)
4. [How to safely carry a fixed-blade knife?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/394/how-to-safely-carry-a-fixed-blade-knife)

Answer (score 2):

**The questions are on topic,** the answers not so much. We should leave these open and write answers that **suggest categories and not specific products**

i.e. recommending down sleeping bags instead of a Marmot down sleeping bag from REI.

Sometimes there will be one standard product for a category (Nalgene bottles, Camelbak bladders, Speedy Stitchers) but we should try and write answers that suggest the broader category instead of the narrow, specific product.

Comment: Note that requiring answers to be more generic could, in some cases, lead to more "Where can I get X?" questions of the form "At [link], Sam recommends the use of devices that perform function Y. I am having difficulty figuring out what kinds of places sell Y's, and I cannot find it online either. I Googled 'companies that sell Y' and all I get are pictures of using Y." A: "There are only 2 companies in the world that sell Y, and they have a weird name for their product so it's hard to search for without knowing what it's called. You want either the Zorb by Arg or the Bayr by Puct."

Comment: ... I have run into situations exactly like what I describe above, where you know there is a device that does X because you see where people have talked about devices that do X, but there is no official term for devices that do X and I don't know any specific companies or product names for any X's. I suppose I'm just saying to be careful that we don't make it impossible for someone to get the information they need.